# php string functions

Tags: php, string

i have page and it has,

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">` 
when i try to change string with strtolower(). it is not working on "Ç,Ö,Ü,Ğ,Ş".

example,
`$str= "ÇaTPÖ";` 
`$str = strtolower($str);`
 
`//$str = "ÇatpÖ";`

also i try to change them with ereg_replace(), but not working again.

`$str = ereg_replace("Ç","ç",$str);`
 
`$str = ereg_replace("Ö","ö",$str);`

Multibyte extension isn't enabled on my server. So i can't use any mb_*-functions.

example,
`$str = mb_strtolower($str, 'windows-1254');`

So what can i do?

Comment: Have you tried `str_replace()` instead of `ereg_replace()`? It's deprecated anyway

Comment: i tried that also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this by changing your locale.

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pt_BR');
```

As long as you know the proper locale to use in place of 'pt_BR', this may work.

Comment: that' good, is this function setlocale as default or that sets for one time? for example, i used this function, and than i open another page on the same server, what is LC_CTYPE now?

Comment: It is set per process. So, each time the server launches a new process the locale changes. LC_CTYPE indicates that the locale setting is for string comparison functions only and should not affect other settings such as date formats.

Answer (score 2):

use mb_strlower
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php

Comment: he wrote : Multibyte extension isn't enabled on my server. So i can't use any mb_*-functions.

Comment: than you have to implement it using array . see this link http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2006/08/10/hot-php-utf-8-tips/